# drawing a graph on subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $U = \{1,2,3\}$. We construct a graph $G = (V,E)$ on $n = 7$ vertices with vertex set $V = \mathcal{P}(U) \setminus \{∅\}$. That is, $v \in V$ is a vertex in $G$ if $v$ is a non-empty subset of $U$.

The vertex set $V$ that I got is $V = \{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\}\}$. I am kinda new to this so I don't understand how can a vertex be a subset?

Comment: You can see it as a label of the vertex. So instead of saying $v_1, \dots, v_7$ you are saying $v_{\{1\}}$ etc.

Comment: See the [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#/media/File:Hasse_diagram_of_powerset_of_3.svg) on [Power set (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) for one such visualization of such a graph, this graph specifically having been a directed graph and including $\emptyset$ as a vertex unlike yours and having rules already defined for where the (*directed*) edges go.  In your case you haven't shared any information as to what edges should exist.

Comment: The question says, "The pair (u,v) is an edge in G if u U v = U, that is, if the union of the two subsets u and v is U." so I think E = { (1, {2,3}), (1, {1,2,3}), (2, {1,3}), (2, {1,2,3}), (3, {1,2}), (3, {1,2,3}) }. Is that correct?

Comment: No, it is not correct.  An edge is a *set* of two vertices.  $1$ is not a vertex here.  $\{1\}$ is.  Ordered pairs are used for *directed* edges.  Here, the edges are not directed.  So, you have edges like $\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$ and $\{\{1\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ and so on.  So, all those you wrote are... after minor corrections... edges.  You forgot also edges who did not involve vertices who are single-element sets... for instance you forgot the edge $\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\}\}$ and $\{\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ etc...

Comment: Now... as for whether you allow loops or not, you might also be missing the edge $\{\{1,2,3\}\}$ (*where both endpoints of the edge are the vertex $\{1,2,3\}$*)